# Apply for Portuguese citizenship from India?

Tags: citizenship, indian-citizens, portuguese-citizens

My father had a Portuguese citizenship. I am a full-time student in India. Can I and my brother claim or acquire Portuguese citizenship through my father?

Comment: Was your father a Portuguese citizen at the time of your birth?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "apply" per-se for Portuguese citizenship in this way.  You either already have it via your parents/grandparents or not.  What you might not have is a passport.

Portugeese nationality law states:
(source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_nationality_law)

> Portuguese by origin are:
>
> - The children of a Portuguese mother or father born in Portuguese    territory
> - The children of a Portuguese mother or father born abroad    if the Portuguese parent is there serving the Portuguese State;
> - The   children of a Portuguese mother or father born abroad **if they have their birth registered at the Portuguese civil registry or
>     if they declare that they want to be Portuguese**;
> - Persons born abroad with, **at least, one Portuguese ascendant** in the second degree (grandparent) of the direct line who has not lost
>     this citizenship.
>
> Naturalisation as a Portuguese citizen
>
> - As of 29 July 2015, those born outside Portugal who have at least **one    grandparent of Portuguese nationality, are granted Portuguese    citizenship by extension immediately**. The new registration procedure
>     replaces the current provision of Article 6, no. 4—according to which 
>     a person who was born abroad and is a 2nd generation descendant of a
>     citizen who has not lost his or her citizenship can acquire
>     Portuguese citizenship by naturalisation, without a residence
>     requirement. The amendment still needs to be signed by the President
>     before entering into law

(My bold)

Therefore, if your parents or Grandparents were Portuguese when you were born then you should have Portuguese citizenship.  Therefore, you should just have to apply for a passport and prove your links to your parents/grandparents and prove that they are Portuguese themselves.

I suggest you contact the embassy in India and ask them what documents you will need to prove these links and what else you might have to provide to obtain a passport.

Answer (score 0):

If he got his citizenship through his parents or birth, yes.

You must apply by sending the appropriate documentation and fees to a "Conservatória de Registo Civil" or to a portuguese consulate in India.